# Removing Phonetics From Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010, phonetics

I am converting excel sheets to html files. in some cases there are phonetics added in some columns, i don't want them in converted html file. how can remove these phonetics while converting...?
Is there any way i can turn off phonetics programmatically..?
here the code i am using

```
xApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
object missing = Type.Missing;
object trueObject = true;
xApp.Visible = false;
xApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
xWorkBook = xApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath, missing, trueObject, missing, missing, missing,
                    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
object format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlHtml;

ConveredFilesPath = Path.Combine(outputDirTemp, ExcelFileName);

string tempFileName = ConveredFilesPath + ".html";
xWorkBook.SaveAs(tempFileName, format, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
if(Directory.Exists(ConveredFilesPath+".files"))
    ConveredFilesPath += ".files";
else
    ConveredFilesPath += "_files";

for (int count = 1; count < xWorkBook.Sheets.Count + 1; count++)
{
    processDetils.AddFileInfo((count).ToString(), ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xWorkBook.Sheets.get_Item(count)).Name);
}
CloseExcelObject(ref xWorkBook, ref xApp);
```

Is there any way i can set phonetics `Turned off` in Excel Object?
Here is the picture of demo excel file the bold characters are phonetics
[image]

Here you can clearly see some cells have phonetics on top but same don't..

Comment: define `phonetics`? Maybe show an example? did you mean the [`=phonetic()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/phonetic-HP005250841.aspx) function?? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: by phonetics i mean  (furigana) characters... i have added  a pciture also..

Comment: hm.. what about something like `ActiveCell.Phonetics.Delete`

Comment: how i can add this to the code given in question ..? means with workBook object or what ..?

Comment: you can't. You need to open the workbook and iterate through sheets and cells which have the phonetics and delete them.

Comment: @me how : thanks for the idea "Phonetics.Delete" didn't worked but "Phonetic.Visible = false" with "ExcelSheet.UsedRange" has done the job for me ...

Answer (score 0):

based on the idea given by `Me how` i have solved this problem by getting number of sheets in the workbook and then setting `Phonetic.visible` property `false`
here is the code

```
Excel.Worksheet NwSheet;
Excel.Range ShtRange;
//Getting Number of total sheets in workbook
int SheetCount = xApp.Sheets.Count;
for (int i = 1; i <= SheetCount; i++){
NwSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xApp.Sheets.get_Item(i);
//Getting all used cells in sheet 
ShtRange = NwSheet.UsedRange;
// hiding phonetics from sheet
ShtRange.Phonetic.Visible = false;
}
```

so now phonetics are not visible in converted `html` file...